# In tornado, is threadpoolexecutor thread-safe?

Tags: asynchronous, tornado

In tornado, we can use ThreadPoolExecutor to execute calls asynchronously, but the ThreadPoolExecutor or @run_on_executor is thread-safe? 
  If the answer is 'no', how to solve the problem of resource sharing?

Answer (score 0):

> Is `ThreadPoolExecutor` thread safe?

`ThreadPoolExecutor` is safe  **as long as your code is safe**. All it does is it runs your code in multiple threads. Ultimately, it's all up to you to make your code thread-safe.

---

> How to solve the problem of resource sharing?

By not sharing the resource. Anytime you need to do anything with the resource you call the main thread and do it there.

In Tornado, you can submit control back to the main thread using [`ioloop.IOLoop.add_callback`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_callback). So, you can run your code in `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but anytime you want to do anything with a resource, you submit control back to the main thread.

---

Example:

```python
x = 1

def print_x():
    global x

    if x == 1:
        print x
        x += 1
```

As you can see, the above code is not thread safe because every thread can modify `x`.

To run it in a thread-safe manner, you'll have to perform the condition check and modify x in the main thread. That is, you'll have to run the `print_x` function only in the main thread, like this:

```python
x = 1

def print_x():
    # run it only in the main thread for thread-safety
    global x

    if x == 1:
        print x
        x += 1

def call_print_x():
    # this can be run in any thread
    # it asks the main thread to run `print_x`

    loop = ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    loop.add_callback(print_x) # submit control to main thread
```

Comment: If loop.add_callback makes response gets slower?

Comment: @shaidiren No. Switching between threads is pretty fast. I mean, I don't think a microsecond of delay matters, does it?